# Custom Keystonejs server-side functions: "No executable schema named 'public'" error

Tags: node.js, server-side, keystonejs

I need to add some custom server-side functions to my KeystoneJS instance. Below is a simple example; the function `userCount` has been added to the exports of the file that initialises Keystone, which should return a count of the number of users.

```
module.exports = {
  keystone,
  apps: [
    new GraphQLApp(),
    new AdminUIApp({
      name: PROJECT_NAME,
      enableDefaultRoute: true,
      authStrategy,
    }),
  ],
  userCount: async () => {
    try {
      const context = keystone.createContext({ skipAccessControl: true });
      console.log(context); // Output below
      const userCount = await keystone.executeGraphQL({
        context,
        query: `query {
          _allUsersMeta {
            count
          }
        }`,
      });
      return userCount;
    } catch (error) {
      return error;
    }
  }
};
```

`Context` seems to be correctly created with the schema name `public` (see console log below), but no matter what I try, I get the following error:

> No executable schema named 'public' is available. Have you setup '@keystonejs/app-graphql'?

This seems to contradict the log below. What am I doing wrong?

`console.log(context)` output:

```
{ 
  schemaName: 'public',
  authedItem: undefined,
  authedListKey: undefined,
  getCustomAccessControlForUser: [Function: getCustomAccessControlForUser],
  getListAccessControlForUser: [Function: getListAccessControlForUser],
  getFieldAccessControlForUser: [Function: getFieldAccessControlForUser],
  getAuthAccessControlForUser: [Function: getAuthAccessControlForUser],
  totalResults: 0,
  maxTotalResults: 1000,
  createContext: [Function],
  executeGraphQL: [Function],
  gqlNames: [Function] 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause of the problem seems to be that I was handling GET requests with a separate Express instance, which I'd set up in addition to the instance used by Keystone.

The solution was to add all my Express logic (e.g. custom endpoints) to the `configureExpress` export in the Keystone `index.js` file, [as per these instructions](https://www.keystonejs.com/guides/custom-server#you-may-not-need-a-custom-server).

A [custom server](https://www.keystonejs.com/guides/custom-server#you-may-not-need-a-custom-server) can be setup for more complicated implementations.